# Why are those objects null when I return to application?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have a MainActivity with a TabLayout and several Fragments. When the application is created everything works fine, however, when the application has run on background and return, I get a nullpointer exception. The objects I created in the OnCreateView method of Fragments are null.

This is my FragmentPagerAdapter class:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private FragmentStrobe fragmentStrobe = null;
    private FragmentFlashLight fragmentFlashLight = null;
    private FragmentDisco fragmentDiscoLight = null;
    private FragmentShaking fragmentShaking = null;
    private FragmentPoliceLights fragmentPoliceLights = null;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                if(fragmentDiscoLight == null){
                    fragmentDiscoLight = new FragmentDisco();
                }
                return fragmentDiscoLight;
            case 1:
                if(fragmentStrobe == null){
                    fragmentStrobe = new FragmentStrobe();
                }
                return fragmentStrobe;
            case 2:
                if(fragmentFlashLight == null){
                    fragmentFlashLight = new FragmentFlashLight();
                }
                return fragmentFlashLight;
            case 3:
                if(fragmentShaking == null){
                    fragmentShaking = new FragmentShaking();
                }
                return fragmentShaking;
            case 4:
                if(fragmentPoliceLights == null){
                    fragmentPoliceLights = new FragmentPoliceLights();
                }
                return fragmentPoliceLights;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity, I have few buttons that are on top of the Fragments. When this button is clicked, I am calling a method in the Fragment;

```
private void initializeButtonStart(){
    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myPreferences.setBoolPreferences(MyPreferences.MY_PREFS_START,
                    !myPreferences.getBoolPreferences(MyPreferences.MY_PREFS_START, MyPreferences.MY_PREFS_START_DEFAULT));

            setIcon();

            ((FragmentInterface) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition())).onRunPermissionChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the code from one Fragment.

```
public class FragmentDisco extends Fragment implements FragmentInterface {

private static final double IMAGE_RATIO = 1.08158;

private View viewBackground;

private View rootView;

private ImageView imageViewDiscoBall;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Disco disco;

private MyPreferences myPreferences;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discolight, container, false);

    disco = new Disco(getContext());

    myPreferences = new MyPreferences(getContext());

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),R.drawable.disco_start);

    initializeView();
    initializeImageView();

    return rootView;
}

private void initializeView(){
    viewBackground = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewMain);
}

private void initializeImageView(){
    imageViewDiscoBall = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.discoBall);

    imageViewDiscoBall.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    imageViewDiscoBall.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            imageViewDiscoBall.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            int width = imageViewDiscoBall.getWidth();
            int resultHeight = (int)((float) width * IMAGE_RATIO);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = imageViewDiscoBall.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = resultHeight;
            imageViewDiscoBall.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    stopDisco();
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected() {
    if(myPreferences == null || imageViewDiscoBall == null || viewBackground == null || disco == null){
        return;
    }

    if(myPreferences.getBoolPreferences(MyPreferences.MY_PREFS_START, MyPreferences.MY_PREFS_START_DEFAULT) &&
            (myPreferences.getIntPreferences(MyPreferences.MY_PREFS_CURRENT_FRAGMENT, MyPreferences.MY_PREFS_CURRENT_FRAGMENT_DEFAULT) == MainActivity.FRAGMENT_DISCO)){
        disco.start(viewBackground, imageViewDiscoBall);
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected() {
    stopDisco();
}

@Override
public void onRunPermissionChanged() {
    if(myPreferences == null || imageViewDiscoBall == null || viewBackground == null || disco == null){
        System.out.println("NULLL !!!!!!");
        return;
    }

    if(myPreferences.getBoolPreferences(MyPreferences.MY_PREFS_START, MyPreferences.MY_PREFS_START_DEFAULT)){
        disco.start(viewBackground, imageViewDiscoBall);
    } else {
        stopDisco();
    }
}

private void stopDisco(){
    if(disco == null || imageViewDiscoBall == null || viewBackground == null){
        return;
    }

    disco.stop();

    viewBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageViewDiscoBall.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
}
```

Most of the time when I return from the background the method that is called in the Fragments prints "NULL!!!". How can I fix this?

Comment: what is `myPreferences`? you didn't show how you declared it. Also you can use debug to determine what exactyl is null.

Comment: I edited the question. I added now the whole Fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

The android is clearing your data from memory to save memory space and power. This might be happening a lot faster if you have a low memory device where the OS has to clear background tasks (also see, if your background taks limit in Settings -> Developers Settings -> Background Process Limit on your device. ) to properly work with foreground app, make sure it gets enough memory, etc resources.

So to prevent this,

- Make large objects only in scope where they are needed like loading image objects where they will be used.
- Use savedInstances to enable your activity to get back to state before.
- For using savedInstances, you have to make your objects serializable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so do I have to save the Fragments in the savedInstances? Maybe you can clarify it?

Comment: No. 
Things like fragments must be created in getFragment method of your adapter. Else nowhere.
This will let you create much memory lighter applications.

Comment: Here is what you should do. Make progress identifying variables like at which part the application was working. Now on 'OnPause()' method, you save this variables in savedInstances. On 'OnResume()' method, android will provide these variables back. So, resume the state in activity. Same goes for fragments, save current state and resume that.
For example, You were in 3rd tab which contains listview and you were doing something on 11th item. So save 3, 11 and work identifier in savedInstances and upon resume, you will move to 3rd tab and then tell fragment to go to 11th item and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to move the functionality from onCreate() to the onResume() method. The onCreate() method is only called when the activity is created, while onResume() is always called when you return back to the activity (exept for the case that is was destroyed). For further information see this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html